# Chart Correlation warnings

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

when I run chart.Correlation I get a series of warnings.  I get the identical warnings with

> chart.Correlation(managers[,1:2],method="pearson")

Here is a short sample:

> ```
> 1: In plot.window(...) : "method" is not a graphical parameter
> 2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "method" is not a graphical parameter
> 3: In title(...) : "method" is not a graphical parameter
> 4: In plot.window(...) : "method" is not a graphical parameter
> 5: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "method" is not a graphical parameter
> 6: In title(...) : "method" is not a graphical parameter
> 7: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
> ```

The charts are produced so I can keep going with the project, but

a) what is going on?
b) Should I be worried of a ticking time bomb
c) can it be fixed?

BTW, I'm running

> R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)  x86_64-w64-mingw32
>
> PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
> xts_0.9-7
> zoo_1.7-11

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to be worried about:

1. Method is the type of correlation which is not a graphical parameter.
2. The method argument is being passed to the pairs function...
3. The function is saying this not a graphical parameter

It can be fixed in the source code (or just ignore it!)